# Unity In-App Purchase Local Validation is slow

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm currently changing our game's in-app purchasing model from an older add-in to unity's built-in service. Up until now there have been no issues testing payments and validating receipts, both live and using sandbox accounts.

Following the Unity guides I have developed a store, and can successfully make new payments with a sandbox account, however local validation takes around 2 minutes on an iPad Air 2. Is this normal? Our previous add-in validated receipt data using the App Store, and took only a few seconds.

```
private bool CheckReceipt()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("IAP: Default for editor, receipt valid.");
        return true;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS
        try
        {
            CrossPlatformValidator validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(),
            AppleTangle.Data(), Application.bundleIdentifier);
            Product product = controller.products.WithID(ProductID);
            string receipt = product.receipt;
            if (receipt == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("IAP: No receipt.");
                return false;
            }
            Debug.Log("IAP: Validating receipt...");    
            IPurchaseReceipt[] result = validator.Validate(receipt);
            return result[0].productID == ProductID;
        }
        catch (IAPSecurityException e)
        {
            Debug.Log("IAP: Invalid receipt, not unlocking content");
            return false;
        }
#endif
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mode "Sandbox" this time for validation very real, when you change paying to "Battle" mode all stand normal

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. Could you elaborate a little? Do you mean that the time delay is only an issue for Sandbox accounts?

Comment: Yes, only for Sandbox accounts

Comment: Is it possible to avoid this delay? For security the receipt's validity needs to be checked multiple times during the game, but we can't make the user wait around 2 minutes every time.

Comment: In normal mode this delay will stand in 5-15 second, in Sandbox mode this not fix